# How to get the wifi name(SSID) of the currently connected wifi in Flutter

Tags: flutter, wifi, ssid

With the help of this [Connectivity Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity), I am able to get the connection status i.e. mobile network, wifi or none using the following code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _connectionStatus = 'Unknown';
  final Connectivity _connectivity = new Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription =
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      setState(() => _connectionStatus = result.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Future<Null> initConnectivity() async {
    String connectionStatus;

    try {
      connectionStatus = (await _connectivity.checkConnectivity()).toString();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      connectionStatus = 'Failed to get connectivity.';
    }


    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _connectionStatus = connectionStatus;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
          child: new Text('Connection Status: $_connectionStatus\n')),
    );
  }
}
```

Now what I want is to get the name of the Wifi when the phone is connected to wifi. 
Detailed Description: Suppose the user has connected his/her phone with a wifi named "Home Wifi", from the code I have wriiten I am only able to get if the phone is connected to wifi or not, I also want to get the name of the wifi if the phone is connected to the wifi i.e. "Home Wifi".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just calling [getWifiName()](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/wifi_info_flutter/wifi_info_flutter/lib/wifi_info_flutter.dart#L39), available in the [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) plugin. This method used to be available in the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin, but it has been moved to this new plugin later.

In iOS, using this solution requires the steps [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732656/796963).

Comment: You can also use the GIT url directly in a pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working fine. I have only checked for android device for now. I hope this works fine on ios too.

Comment: I would also love to know how can I add the git url directly as Randal mentioned.

Comment: Ah, here's [how to add directly from git](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) as @RandalSchwartz mentioned. I saw it once but totally forgot. You would have to use `git: url: git@github.com:flutter/plugins.git` and `path: packages/connectivity`.

Comment: So I've gotten this to work in android, but in ios i'm getting an exception ```PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, wifi name unavailable, null)```. Permission problem?

Comment: @Rob C, Yes, I think it deserves a new question! :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716751/flutter-ios-reading-wifi-name-using-the-connectivity-plugin

Comment: I always receive <unknown ssid> when I called ```getWifiName```.

Comment: @Dhaval Kansara, is it iOS? Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732656/796963 ?

Comment: @Feu Yes, I have already added Access Wifi Information for my project.

Comment: The BSSID may be null, if there is no network currently connected. "02:00:00:00:00:00", if the caller has insufficient permissions to access the BSSID. found this from android developer site but don't know how to add permissons

Comment: @Feu I am also using connectivity plugin to get wifi ssid for IOS with the method connectivity.getWifiName(), but it returns null, but I can get IP with getWifiIP() method. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Feu this is my attempt 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857789/connectivity-plugin-getwifiname-method-to-get-ssid-returns-null-in-flutter-f

Comment: This is no longer null safe

Comment: Anything for web?!

Answer (score 5):

In 2022, I have switched to [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) library, in my case this new version is better than the old one. And it still uses the same method names as the old version to get the name of wifi: `getWifiName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) package.

Add this code to android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

2. 

```
Future<void> setNetwork() async {
final info = NetworkInfo();
var locationStatus = await Permission.location.status;
if (locationStatus.isDenied) {
  await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
}
if (await Permission.location.isRestricted) {
  openAppSettings();
}

if (await Permission.location.isGranted) {
  var wifiName = await info.getWifiName();
  log('wifiName $wifiName');
  }
}
```