# Flutter IOS reading wifi name using the connectivity or wifi plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, wifi, connectivity

This question is similar [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498906/how-to-get-the-wifi-namessid-of-the-currently-connected-wifi-in-flutter), but slightly different.

I am trying to retrieve the name of my currently connected wifi network using the [Connectivity Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506351/4876579) works perfectly fine in android, and while it sounds like it should work for iOS, I am getting an exception:

```
PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, wifi name unavailable, null)
```

Simple ex. of the code causing the exception (with the assumption I am connected to wifi, also not using an emulator):

```
Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();
print(await (connectivity.getWifiName()));
```

My gut is telling me it may be permission related, but honestly I am not sure.

Cheers and thanks!

**Edit:**

I just realized, the exception above is thrown by the [wifi plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi), which I was also experimenting with.

```
print(await (Wifi.ssid));
```

Connectivity simply returns null...

Comment: apparently it stopped working on iOS12, I'll give it a check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll see if I can fix that in the plugin's code. If so, I'll get back to this answer.

However, for now, adding the capability to your project (or simply switching it `ON`) on Xcode will do it: (no code change in your app required)

```
# on your project folder, run:
open -a xcode ./ios
```

### In Xcode 12+

On `Target > Runner > Signing & Capabilities`, use the `+ Capability` button to add the `Access WiFi Information` capability to your project.

[image: adding capability]

### In older Xcode versions

On `Runner > Capabilities`, switch `Access WiFi Information` to `on`.

See:

[image: switching WiFi information ON]

Comment: Thank you for looking at this!

Comment: In my case I am only I am not able to see this on/off switch button. Can anybody let me know that how can I access it.

Comment: in my case it's still return null