# Connectivity plugin "getWifiName()" method to get ssid returns null in flutter for ios 13+

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get wifi ssid in flutter for ios(13+) with connectivity plugin but result returns null. I have added access wireless information from Xcode but still not working. Can anyone help out please?

```
Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async{
    switch(result){
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
        String wifiName;
        try {
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            LocationAuthorizationStatus status =
            await _connectivity.getLocationServiceAuthorization();
            if (status == LocationAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {
              print('wifiName notDetermined: ');
              status = await _connectivity.requestLocationServiceAuthorization();
            }
            if (status == LocationAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways ||
                status == LocationAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
              print('wifiName authorizedWhenInUse: ');
              wifiName = await _connectivity.getWifiName();
              setState(() {
                _ssid = wifiName != null ? wifiName : _ssid;
              });

            } else {
              print('wifiName ,.,.,.,: ');
              wifiName = await _connectivity.getWifiName();
            }
          } else {
            LocationAuthorizationStatus status =
            await _connectivity.getLocationServiceAuthorization();
//            if(status == )
            wifiName = await _connectivity.getWifiName();
            print('android wifi');
            print(wifiName);
          }
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
          wifiName = "Failed to get Wifi Name";
        }

        setState(() {
          _connectionStatus ='result '+ '$result\n'
              'Wifi Name: $wifiName\n';
          print('_connectionStatus $_connectionStatus');
        });
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Connected to mobile network');
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Connected to no network');
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result.toString());
        break;
  default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = 'Failed to get connectivity.');
        break;
    }
  }
```

I have tried with above code from connectivity plugin example. Also there is showing 'As of iOS 13, Apple announced that these APIs will no longer return valid information'. So how to achieve my goal?

Comment: hi, interesting issue. I can't take a look at it right now, but try taking a look into this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65093

Comment: okay please, it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, the flutter team decided to create a new plugin for wifi information, removing these methods from the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin.

So check the [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) plugin: the method signatures are just the same.

As on being able to access this on iOS 13+, according to the [package's readme](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus):

> The CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo will work for Apps that:
>
> - The app uses Core Location, and has the user’s authorization to use
>   location information.
> - The app uses the NEHotspotConfiguration API to configure the current
>   Wi-Fi network.
> - The app has active VPN configurations installed.
>
> If your app falls into the last two categories, it will work as it is.
> If your app doesn't fall into the last two categories, and you still
> need to access the wifi information, you should request user's
> authorization to use location information.
>
> There is a helper method provided in this plugin to request the
> location authorization: requestLocationServiceAuthorization. To
> request location authorization, make sure to add the following keys to
> your Info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist:
>
> NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription - describe why the app
> needs access to the user’s location information all the time
> (foreground and background). This is called Privacy - Location Always
> and When In Use Usage Description in the visual editor.
> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription - describe why the app needs
> access to the user’s location information when the app is running in
> the foreground. This is called Privacy - Location When In Use Usage
> Description in the visual editor.

So basically, from iOS13 on, you have to request the user's permission for location - it actually makes sense.

Comment: i will let you know after test